# Pinpointing the difference and changes made between two pages in magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento, layout

I have two pages that should be using the exact same template and layout.

The correct item layout can be seen below.
http://dokha.co/index.php/medwakh/custom-medwakh-from-white-horse-studios-13.html

The incorrect item layout is below.
http://dokha.co/index.php/shisha-tobacco/al-fakher-shisha-tobacco-1.html

As you can see in the first image the layout of the item is compact. In the second link it is all drawn out.

I am curious to know if you can tell me how to make the second one like the first one, The compact style. I am not sure what modifications could have been made in magento to cause the layout to only show up that way for specific items, as only the items in the category on link 1 behave that way, I would like to know how to make them all behave this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first thing: the layouts are slightly different because in the first example, you have simple product and in the second example you have a configurable product.

So, view.phtml is including different templates in each.

Regardless though, the actually culprit of the expanded space you are seeing in the second example is being caused by a clearing div.  Simply remove it.

The div you are looking for is this:

```
<div class="clearer"></div>
```

and you will find it in `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`