# Magento template/layout how to make changes to product view

Tags: html, css, magento, layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pinpointing the difference and changes made between two pages in magento 1.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126112/pinpointing-the-difference-and-changes-made-between-two-pages-in-magento-1-6-2)

http://dokha.co/index.php/shisha-tobacco/al-fakher-shisha-tobacco-108.html
As you can see from the link above the product page is disorganized to some degree.

I have made some modifications below, in firebug, and took a screenshot. Can anyone advise on how to put these changes into effect?

[image]

Comment: what version of magento are you on and has there been any changes made? ... are you looking to only do css changes or some form of html changes as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to move up the "Select a Flavor" block?

Look at the source and delete the DOM node `<div class="clearer"></div>`. I use google Chrome browser because it is very easy to do things just like this. I right-clicked on **Select a Flavor** then selected Inspect Element. In the lower pane, I navigated up until the clearer block and deleted that.

Answer (score 1):

To make the css changes to your page. Please create a custom.css file in the skin/frontend/yourfolder/css/custom.css and add the styles which you made in the browser.

Personally, I use Google Chrome browser to make changes to the page and then copy into the customised .css file. 
It is always best practise not to replace in the default .css but use a customised version, so you have a version of the original file.

Hope it helps.

Cheers